# controlling and comparing dates from date picker with simplDateFormat

Tags: android, datepicker, simpledateformat

I'm implementing a reservation service , so i need to make a control on the entry and exit dates ; i'm getting both dates via Date Picker and setting thme on EditText.
my EditText are assigned with the two variables: entryField & exitField.
it seems that the dates are unparsable from the Log output below.

this is a part of my code :

```
OnDateSetListener ondate = new OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {
      switch (IDclick){

          case 1:
         entryField.setText(String.valueOf(monthOfYear)+"-"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+"-"+String.valueOf(year));

              break;
          case 2:
          exitField.setText(String.valueOf(monthOfYear)+"-"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+"-"+String.valueOf(year));

          break;

      }
      }
 };

 public void dateControl(EditText date1, EditText date2 ){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
try {
Log.i("DATE","entry date ="+entryField);
Log.i("DATE","exit date ="+exitField);
Log.i("DATE","date1 ="+date1);
Log.i("DATE","date2 ="+date2);

    Date mdate1 =sdf.parse(date1.toString());
    Date mdate2 =sdf.parse(date2.toString());



Log.i("DATE","mdate1 ="+mdate1);
Log.i("DATE","mdate2 ="+mdate2);

if (mdate1.compareTo(mdate2)>0) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Invalid Date")
                .setMessage("Please check your dates !")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        entryField.setText("");
                        exitField.setText("");
                    }
                }).show();
    }

}catch (ParseException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
```

}
     }

i'm using the dateControl method up ; with two parameters : entryField and exitField.
the problem is that i got this output on the LOG : unparsable date !!!

```
05-30 09:36:14.970    1159-1159/com.example.app I/DATE﹕ entry date =android.widget.EditText@53a0f9d8
05-30 09:36:14.970    1159-1159/com.example.app I/DATE﹕ exit date =android.widget.EditText@53a109a8
05-30 09:36:14.974    1159-1159/com.example.app I/DATE﹕ date1 =android.widget.EditText@53a0f9d8
05-30 09:36:14.974    1159-1159/com.example.app I/DATE﹕ date2 =android.widget.EditText@53a109a8
05-30 09:36:14.978    1159-1159/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "android.widget.EditText@53a0f9d8" (at offset 0)
05-30 09:36:14.982    1159-1159/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
05-30 09:36:14.982    1159-1159/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at com.example.app.Reservation.dateControl(Reservation.java:220)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Date mdate1 =sdf.parse(date1.toString());
Date mdate2 =sdf.parse(date2.toString());
```

to

```
Date mdate1 =sdf.parse(date1.getText().toString());
Date mdate2 =sdf.parse(date2.getText().toString());
```

If you do `date1.toString()` it will return `String` representation of `date1`(i.e. `EditText`).

If you want to get the text from the `EditText` you need to call `getText()`